# Boost Metafunction class higher order function

Tags: c++, boost, functional-programming, c++11, boost-mpl

What's the difference between metafunction classes and placeholders and higher order functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost provides features for Metafunctions and higher order functions, but the concepts are not specific to Boost.

the term "metafunction" describes a template metaprogramming technique for using template specialisation to allow the compiler to make decisions at compile time depending on their template argument.

typically, a metafunction *could* look something like this

```
template<bool B>
struct my_metafunction
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};

template<>
struct my_metafunction<false>
{
    enum { value = 0 };
};
```

When `my_metafunction` is used, the exact value of `my_metafunction<B>::value` will depend on the value of **B** (i.e. `my_metafunction<true>::value` will be different to `my_metafunction<false>::value`).       If you're unfamiliar with template metaprogramming then you're probably wondering *why* this is useful - and the reality is that it's generally only useful for people writing libraries which heavily use templates and compile-time decision making.   (template metaprogramming is a whole different paradigm!)

---

on the other hand, "higher order function" describes a functional programming technique which allows you to pass functions as function arguments.   This is a little easier to express in standard C++ with the standard `<algorithm>` library working with standard containers.

for example, C++ includes a higher-order function called `transform` - its purpose is to step through each element in a container (such as a vector, string, list, map, array, etc) and perform a transformation for each element.

```
std::string str = "Hello, World";
std::transform(str.begin(),
               str.end(),
               str.begin(),
               std::toupper); // Note - toupper is a function!

std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

The transformation performed is dependent on its final parameter, `std::toupper`.   the purpose of std::toupper is to accept a (character) value and return the uppercase version of that value.   std::transform grabs the result of toupper for each element between `str.begin()` and `str.end()`  (and in this example, the result gets put back into str)

There are plenty of other examples of higher-order functions in the standard library - `std::find_if`, `std::sort`, `std::count_if`, to name a few.    Higher-order functions in C++ can typically accept any kind of callable object, including a function, a lambda or a function object.
The callable objects which are passed are often referred to as [i]predicates[/i] (Although I'm not totally sure if that's the correct usage of the term "predicate")

---

the Boost placeholders are part of another aspect of functional programming known as *currying* - which allows you to 'bind' parameters to a function before that function is called.  (in the world of Boost, the outcome of currying is a function-object which is usually passed to a higher-order function).

Currying is intended as an alternative to writing your own custom specialised callable object, by reusing existing callable objects/predicates and setting some of their arguments in concrete before they're used.

For example, you could use the higher-order-function `find_if` to search a string for the first character which is "greater than q".  the C++ standard library includes a callable object called `greater_equals`, except it needs a second parameter to be used by find_if ("Greater than and equals **to what??")

Without currying, you might write a function (ignore all case-sensitivity for now) such as

```
bool greater_than_or_equals_to_q(char c)
{
    return c >= 'Q';
}
```

with currying, you could "bind" the character 'Q` to the greater_equals function in order to create a predicate which only accepts a single argument, and represents a predicate yielding true when its argument is "greater than or equal to Q".

```
std::bind( std::greater_equal<char>(), 
           std::placeholders::_1, 
           'Q' );
```

So, using the uppercase string:

```
std::string str = "HELLO WORLD";
auto gt_eq_Q = std::bind( std::greater_equal<char>(), 
                          std::placeholders::_1, 
                          'Q' );

auto iter = std::find_if( str.begin(), str.end(), gt_eq_Q );
std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
```

The output, as expected - the first character in "HELLO WORLD" which is greater-than-or-equal-to 'Q' happens to be 'W'

```
W
```

Comment: Possibly the wrong placeholders the OP wants to know about. Boost.MPL has higher-order metafunctions (although the OP did mention functions), like `less<_1, _2>`. [Relevant docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/tutorial/tutorial-metafunctions.html).

Comment: A "predicate" is function that evaluates a condition on some object (or objects), returning whether the condition is true or not. As such it's reasonably common for higher-order functions to take predicate functions as arguments (e.g. a filter function that returns all elements of a collection that meet some condition would take a function to test the condition, so you don't have to rewrite the filter function for every possible condition). So a predicate is basically a particular *kind* of thing you pass to a higher-order function; it's not correct to always call them predicates.

Answer (score 4):

For detailed explanations have a look at

1. http://www.artima.com/cppsource/metafunctions.html
2. http://www.mywikinet.com/mpl/paper/mpl_paper.pdf

In principle a metafunction is either:

- a class template in which all the parameters are types
- a class with publicly accessible type `type`

For example:

```
template <bool, class L, class R>
struct IF
{
  typedef R type; 
};

template <class L, class R>
struct IF<true, L, R>
{
  typedef L type; 
};
```

A function that operates on another function is known as a higher-order function. So, higher-order metafunction is a metafunction that accepts other metafunctions as parameters and use them during computation. This is conceptually similar to a function accepting a pointer to another function or a function object as a parameter at run-time. Only difference is that metafunctions exist only at compile-time. `boost::mpl::transform` is an example of such a higher order metafunction.